# Spring: Value is null when an object is injected to both base and child class beans

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a parent abstract class and a concrete child class. The abstract one has one concrete method and one other abstract method, which the child class implements. Both of these classes are configured as Spring beans. The code snippets are similar to below:

Spring Config:

```
<bean id="parent" class="Parent" abstract="true">
  <property name="propA" ref="propA"/>
  <property name="cacheMan" ref="cacheMan"/>
</bean>

<bean id="child" class="Child" parent="parent">
  <property name="propB" ref="propB"/>
  <property name="cacheMan" ref="cacheMan"/>
</bean>

<!-- Of course, cacheMan is defined elsewhere and not relevant here.-->
```

Class definitions:

```
    public abstract class Parent {
      private A propA; // A is irrelevant.
      private CacheManager cacheMan; // This is the object in question.
      public void doProcess1() {
         //code logic
         if (cacheMan == null) {
            // Error!
         }
      }
      public void doProcess2();
    }

    public class Child extend Parent {
      private B propB; // Again, B is irrelevant.
      private CacheManager cacheMan; // This is the object in question.
      public void doProcess2() {
         //code logic
      }
    }


public class Test {
        private Parent parent; //Assume this is Spring injected and it's of type Child.
        public void doTest() {
          parent.doProcess1(); // Error thrown since cacheMan is null.
        }
}
```

Both of these classes have appropriate getter/setter methods for `cacheMan`. I don't understand how `cacheMan` is being null in the `doProcess1()` method. However, if i change that line from

`cacheMan == null` to `getCacheMan() == null`, the error is not thrown.

I think the `getCacheMan()` is retrieving the object injected to the child class, since `parent` is of the instance `Child` and that's why it's not being null.

Please shed some light on it and let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not related to Spring but to Java language - method overriding to be specific.

You have `setCacheMan()` (that's what I assume) method defined in both abstract parent and child class. When Spring calls that method, it always calls the overriden version in child - and that version modifies `cacheMan` reference in child as well. `cacheMan` reference in parent is never really touched because the only method that accesses it is overriden in child.

> if i change that line from `cacheMan == null` to `getCacheMan() == null`, the error is not thrown.

That is quite obvious from what has already been said - `getCacheMan()` is also overriden! `cacheMan` reference in parent is `null` (see above), but since `getCacheMan()` is overriden, it accesses `cacheMan` in child, not in parent. Effectively you have two variables, but the one in child can't be upated.

Solution: the idea of parent bean is to have common dependencies in one place and avoid duplicating them in every child:

```
<bean id="parent" class="Parent" abstract="true">
  <property name="propA" ref="propA"/>
  <property name="cacheMan" ref="cacheMan"/>
</bean>

<bean id="child" class="Child" parent="parent">
  <property name="propB" ref="propB"/>
</bean>
```

And either declare `cacheMan` protected or have at least protected getter so that child classes can access it. Do not create `cacheMan` field in child classes.

Comment: Tomasz, i believe you're giving me an explanation i guessed of, but I don't really get it. Why doesn't the abstract hold a separate cacheMan on its own. I understand that the child class overrides it, but that problem would've been like "why i'm getting the child's instance instead of parent's?" I don't know how null is a qualified value to be injected to the Parent's cacheMan field.

Comment: @asgs: that's the thing, `null` is never injected to your parent! I think Spring calls `setCacheMan()` twice - once for parent and once for child, providing correct `cacheMan` reference in both invocations. However, since the method is overriden, `setCacheMan()` in child is called twice and `setCacheMan()` in parent - never. Again, this has very little to do with Spring, this is how Java works. Please add `System.out` to both `setCacheMan()` implementations and see when are they invoked. I bet the version in parent is never called - and the `cacheMan` reference in parent is never updated.

Comment: I added an SOP in both of the Setters and it indeed invokes both of them, in the order: parent and then child (during the server starup), because Child is dependent on Parent. I don't know what happens after that, that makes the parent's cacheMan to be set to null.